# AWS Transcribe using C#.net

Tags: aws-sdk

I am trying to get a list of `ListTranscriptionJobs` or `StartTranscriptionJob` using `Amazon.TranscribeService` but getting exception Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

At the same time from same PC and using same key I am able to access above methods from Amazon CLI and Python code.

What can I do to fix this?

```
try
        {
            AmazonTranscribeServiceClient client =
                new AmazonTranscribeServiceClient("Access Key ID", "Secret Access Key", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            if (client != null)
            {
                // Define the cancellation token.
                CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = source.Token;

                ListTranscriptionJobsRequest requestListTranscriptionJobs =
                    new ListTranscriptionJobsRequest
                    {
                        Status = TranscriptionJobStatus.FAILED
                    };
                // here is error:
                ListTranscriptionJobsResponse resp = await client.ListTranscriptionJobsAsync(requestListTranscriptionJobs, token);
               }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Comment: update version 3.3.22 of AWSSDK.Core 
3.3.1.1 of AWSSDK.TranscribeService will resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prads my code is not working till I won't get updated dlls which released today, after updating this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked.
Make Sure that

You have latest SDK (Download from https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)
use correct awsAccessKeyId and awsSecretAccessKey